# CodeWars task 5ky Greed is Good

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I came across a task called [Greed is Good](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5270d0d18625160ada0000e4/train/javascript)  in CodeWars. The task is the game with rules. You are given an array with numbers and you need to return the final score according to rules.

Rules:

```
 Three 1's => 1000 points
 Three 6's =>  600 points
 Three 5's =>  500 points
 Three 4's =>  400 points
 Three 3's =>  300 points
 Three 2's =>  200 points
 One   1   =>  100 points
 One   5   =>   50 point
```

So if we have array with elements [ 5 1 3 4 1 ] the result will be 250 points and so on.

I tried implement the solution  and divided the task into several tasks. I wrote function that counts occurrences in array and it returns objects with value and counts -> { v: '3', c: '2' } for example. And then i use array functions to find elements that fulfill the condition and calculate the sum. My code have passed first tests, but next didn't.

The main problem that i need count characters according the rules for example if we have an array with five 1 i need count them like { v: "1", c: 4, v: "1", c: 1 }. My implementation counts them all and than my code makes no sense. So I'm trying to find another solution how to write it simpler and consider the issue above.

My code:

```
const rules = [
    { v: '1', c: 3, p: 1000 },
    { v: '6', c: 3, p: 600 },
    { v: '5', c: 3, p: 500 },
    { v: '4', c: 3, p: 400 },
    { v: '3', c: 3, p: 300 },
    { v: '2', c: 3, p: 200 },
    { v: '1', c: 1, p: 100 },
    { v: '5', c: 1, p: 50 }
]

const score = (dice) => {
    const values = countValuesFromArr(dice)

    const sum = values.map((el) => rules.filter((rulesEl) => rulesEl.v === el.v && rulesEl.c === el.c ? rulesEl.p : 0)).flat().reduce((a, b) => a + b.p )

    return sum
}

const countValuesFromArr = (arr) => {
    let counter = {}

    for (el of arr) {
        if (counter[el]) {
            counter[el] += 1
        } else {
            counter[el] = 1
        }
    }

    const values = Object.keys(counter).map(key => {
        return { v: key, c: counter[key] };
    });

    return values
}
```

Comment: If you ask a question about CodeWars, it would help if you provide a link to the challenge itself so people can test their answers before providing them to you

Comment: Just edited a question and provided a link

Comment: Here's my solution: https://pastebin.com/qXprJPCx I've added comments to what exactly I did, so that'll help you to understand where you went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!!! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you only apply the score when `rulesEl.c === el.c`, but it could be that `el.c` is greater than `rulesEl.c`, in which case you should determine *how many times* that `c` can be subtracted from `el.c` and apply the score that many times. The remainder (if any) should then still serve to potentially apply other rules. So this logic cannot work with `rules.filter`, as that (wrongly) implies you can only apply a rule once for a certain digit.

I would actually iterate the rules first, as then you don't need to call `filter`. Instead the rule will give you the property for the `counter` so you don't need to look for it through iteration.

Here is how that could look:

```
function score( dice ) {
    const counters = [null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    for (const value of dice) counters[value]++;
    return rules.reduce((score, {v, c, p}) => {
        const quot = Math.floor(counters[v] / c); // How many times can we apply the rule?
        score += quot * p;  // Apply it that many times
        counters[v] %= c;   // And remove the used digits
        return score;
    }, 0);
}
```